Conga Composer SOQL Limits reached
I know this subject only has a few number of people but any help would be appricated.
I currently have these systems installed:

Salesforce CPQ
Conga Composer
Conga CFS (Clause Library)

I have a custom object created in Salesforce for relating clauses with Quote and Lines.
The issue I am faced with is that in order for me to get data to show in the composer template, I need to create Conga Queries (SOQL), fetch the data, add it to a solution and then be able to call that data. However, due to the limitation, Conga Solutions only allows me to have 50 SOQL queries.
The work I am currently doing is very large and it means I reach the 50 limit way before 25% can be done. I think even if I upgraded to another edition the max is 100 and still wont be enough for me to call each of the product related clauses from quote lines or static clauses from the CFS.
Due to the requirement and ever changing of clauses, I cannot have the static data in the conga template directly. Which leaves me no choice but use queries from Conga queries.
I am asking to see if there is an alternative way to get the data to show on a Conga template (even without using conga solution) as I have reached the limit.
Many thanks in advance.

Here are a few alternatives you can try:
Use Salesforce Reports:
Create reports with the data and use them in Conga Composer. Reports can handle more data and avoid the query limit.
Optimize Queries:
Combine related data in fewer queries to stay within the limit.
Custom Apex Code:
You can write an Apex class to collect and organize your data, and then use that data in Conga Composer.
If these options don’t work, you might want to look into other document generation tools that don’t have this limitation.
